# How to keep images side by side using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My aim is to keep 2 images side by side in large screens and one above another in small screens.The problem what I have done is doing the opposite.In large screens images are coming one above another and in small screens images are coming side by side.

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMYKY/23/).

This is my html code

```
<!--nav bar-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-18">
<div >
    <img src="http://www.computerhope.com/logo.gif" alt="Logo"  class="round"> my user
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">Recently purchased
<div id="slideshow">
  <span class="images">
<div class="box img-responsive">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/abstract" />
<span class="caption simple-caption">
                    <p>Review</p>
                </span>
</div>
<div class="box img-responsive">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/food" />
<span class="caption simple-caption">
                    <p>Review</p>
                </span></div>
  </span>

  <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have not posted the js codes because I feel its not necessary But if you want then please check the fiddle

Please see the screenshot,[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `img-responsive` class to image tag and not div tag. Also `col-lg-18` not possible to have 18 columns unless you have customised it, by default 12 is the max columns u can have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I am using 24 grid system.so using col-lg-18

Comment: `<div class="col-md-6">` change it to `<div class="col-md-12">` and try

Comment: As I said I am using 24 grid system.So I am assiging 18 for users(right side of the page) and 6 for images(images should be left side)

Comment: any solutions do you have?

Comment: i am try out in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks again for trying to answer.Actually I want my user on left side and recently purchased on right side.BUt in the bootply everything is coming on right side

Comment: do check the link i gave bootply.com/113627

Comment: delete the comment containg your email